# Поиск в многомерном массиве по идентификатору

Tags: php, массивы

не могу понять как реализовать. Есть два массива на руках.
Первый массив лежит в БД

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 65
        [NAME] => Велосипед.
        [CODE] => 204491
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 66
        [NAME] => Самокат
        [CODE] => 23572
    )

)
```

Второй получаю по запросу к сервису

```
Array
(
[1016] => Array
    (
        [code] => 204491
        [manufacturer] => Г Поль-Боскамп
        [name] => Велосипед
    )

[9818] => Array
    (
        [code] => 23572
        [manufacturer] => Г Поль-Боскамп
        [name] => Самокат

    )
[1012] => Array
    (
        [code] => 54864
        [manufacturer] => Г Поль-Боскамп
        [name] => Ролики

    )

)
```

Мне необходимо проверять есть ли такие элементы в базе(первый массив) которые пришли из запроса (второй массив), чтоб не дублировать. А к примеру если нет такого то выполнять действия по добавлению.

Comment: Что из показанного должно добавиться и почему?

Comment: а если есть такой в базе? или мб есть но данные различаются? Если речь таки про базу в итоге, дак может влить во временную таблицу все, а потом пропадейтить одним запросом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($arrayFromService as $one)
  {
  $code = $one['code'];
  $exists = false;

  foreach($arrayFromDB as $two) /* Проверим наличие в массиве из базы */
    {
    if($two['CODE'] == $code )
      {
      $exists = true;
      break;
      }
    }

   if(!$exists)
    {
    $newcode = $code;
    $newname = $two['name'];
    /*
    Код добавления
    */
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//$arrFromDB = [...];
//$arrFromService = [...];

$codes = array_column($arrFromDB, 'CODE');
foreach ($arrFromService as $item) {
    $existPosition = array_search(
        $item['code'], 
        $codes
    );

    if ($existPosition === false) {
        // вставляем новую запись
    }
}
```

`array_column` создаёт для вас новый массив вида `[code1, code2 ...]`.

`array_search` ищет в новом массиве нужное значение.

Используйте это, нативные функции всегда быстрее.
[Замеры скорости](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3bd59cf00a68abc69066c4d28b1e6827a9fa40a1)

```
native array_column:: 0.00055694580078125
foreach array_column: 0.00070595741271973
native array_search:: 0.0000259876251221
foreach array_search: 0.00023508071899414
```

Comment: нет, это неправда, нативные функции функции медленнее работают. их  используют  чтобы код читать можно было, а не так как сверху ответы

Comment: https://habr.com/post/340696/

Comment: @MykolaVeriga вы правы, если дело касается функций с коллбеками, поскольку в каждой итерации происходит вызов функции. А в данном случае быстрее нативные. Прикладываю в ответ измерения

Answer (score -1):

> ...Есть два массива на руках...

то так:

```
$array_first = [
    ['ID'  => '65', 'NAME' => 'Велосипед.', 'CODE' => '204491'],
    ['ID'  => '66', 'NAME' => 'Самокат', 'CODE' => '23572'],
];

$array_second = [
    '1016' => ['code'  => '204491', 'manufacturer' => 'Г Поль-Боскамп', 'name' => 'Велосипед'],
    '9818' => ['code'  => '23572', 'manufacturer' => 'Г Поль-Боскамп', 'name' => 'Самокат'],
    '1012' => ['code'  => '54864', 'manufacturer' => 'Г Поль-Боскамп', 'name' => 'Ролики'],
];


//  Приведем массив в нормальный вид
$new_array = [];
array_walk($array_first, function ($item, $key) use (&$new_array) {
    $new_array[$item['CODE']] = ['NAME' => $item['NAME'], 'ID' => $item['ID']];
});
$array_first = $new_array;

//  Проверяем
foreach ($array_second as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($array_first[$value['code']])) {
        if ($array_first[$value['code']]['NAME'] == $value['name']) {
            // Элементы идентичны
            var_dump('1 - '.$value['code']);
        } else {
            // Различие в названии
            // ПРИМЕР: "Велосипед." в первом массиве и "Велосипед" во втором
            var_dump('2 - '.$value['code']);
        }
    }else{
        // Элемент не существует
        var_dump('3 - '.$value['code']);
    }
}
```